# Error In Sending Mail From Local Host To Gmail

Tags: c#, asp.net, smtpclient

I am just testing the email sending from local host to gmail.com

```
***Webconfig:***

<system.net>
<mailSettings>
  <smtp>
    <network 
      host="localhost"
       port="25"
        />
  </smtp>
</mailSettings>
</system.net>

***Default.aspx:***

<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Default.aspx.cs"  Inherits="MasterApps._Default" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"  "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
<head runat="server">
<title>Untitled Page</title>
</head>
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div>
    <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" OnClick="Button1_Click" Text="Button" />      

</div>
</form>
</body>
</html>

***Code behind is:***

protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

        MailAddress from = new MailAddress("mwaghela7@gmail.com");
        MailAddress to = new MailAddress("mwaghela7@gmail.com");
        MailMessage msg = new MailMessage(from, to);
        msg.Subject = "hi";
        msg.Body = "hello";
        SmtpClient sc = new SmtpClient();
        sc.Send(msg);

}
```

It’s fired error like:

> *An exeception of type ‘System.Net.Mail.smtp
>   failedReceipientExeception’ occurred in System.dll but was not
>   handlled in user code. Additional Information: MailBox unavailable.The
>   server response was:5.7.1. Unable to Relay for mwaghela7@gmail.com

What’s wrong in above code? How to solve this?

Answer (score 3):

Well in most cases the email fails to send because of the port number specified or because you didn't establist secure connection. Try this alternative. Click [here](http://www.emailarchitect.net/easendmail/) you can download some class files for sending email to all domains. First add reference to EASendMail. And then code like this.

```
using EASendMail;
 SmtpMail oMail = new SmtpMail("Tryit");
                    SmtpClient oSmtp = new SmtpClient();

            //        
                    oMail.From = "eamil";

            //        // Set recipient email address
                    oMail.To = "email@domain.com";

                    // Set email subject
                   oMail.Subject = "subject";

                    // Set email body
                    oMail.TextBody = "body";


                    SmtpServer oServer = new SmtpServer("smtp.gmail.com");


                    oServer.User = "email";
                    oServer.Password = "password";



                   oServer.Port = 465;

            //detect SSL type automatically
                 oServer.ConnectType = SmtpConnectType.ConnectSSLAuto;
                    oSmtp.SendMail(oServer, oMail);
```

Answer (score 0):

It can be possible that your mail server does not support anonymous to send mail.You just could send mail to the user who in your mail server.

Although edit your web.config code as below and then try:

```
<system.net>
    <mailSettings>
        <smtp deliveryMethod="Network">
            <network host="localhost"
                port="25"
                from="no-reply@me.com"/>
        </smtp>
    </mailSettings>
</system.net>
```

Comment: It's fired error like "systemconfigurationErrorException and Unrecognized from attributes which is define below port attributes.

Comment: thamba jara,jevan karatoy, mi check karen zalyawar

Comment: from="no-reply@me.com" have you written appropriate addess in this?

Comment: yes, but I haven't seen "from" attributes in smtp tag.It means it not available the "from" attributes that's why error like unrecognized "From" attributes throws..

Answer (score 0):

Try this.
`

```
using (var client = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com", 587))
            {
                client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("you@gmail.com","password");
               var mail = new MailMessage();
                mail.From = new MailAddress("email");
                mail.To.Add("email");
                mail.Subject = "something";
                mail.Body = "body";
               client.Send(mail);
```

`

Comment: Error: "SMTP server requires secure connection or the client was not authenticate"